# Wifi (through usb wireless adapter) does not connect automatically

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I used to be able to connect (automatically on start-up) to the Internet using a USB wireless adapter. One day, after start-up, Ubuntu said that it experienced an "internal error", something having to do with the indicator. I did not pay attention, but on next start-up I did not get connected to the internet. The indicator did not show any connections available. Since then, I connect manually:

```
sudo modprobe r8188eu rtw_power_mgnt=0
```

Note that I have a file `/etc/modprobe.d/r8188eu.conf` with the following contents:

```
options r8188eu rtw_power_mgnt=0
```

How can I cause Ubuntu to connect on start-up as it used to do before the crash?

**UPDATE** Though a hack, I ended up simply putting the above command (without `sudo`) in `/etc/rc.local`.